# Careers Select - list of current events

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, careers-select

I recently saw an ad on Stack Overflow for [Careers Select Toronto](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/select/event/ca7/toronto-web-developers?).  The idea intrigued me, although I'm not currently living in the Toronto area so I didn't submit my profile.  Doing a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acareers.stackoverflow.com%2Fselect%2f) reveals that they have done this before for New York, Los Angeles and London, UK as well.

I've looked around a bunch, using logical URLs and peeking in the sitemap, but I can't seem to find a listing page with the current Careers Select events.  In the [questions page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/select/event/ca7/toronto-web-developers/questions), they say if you are not in Toronto to *"hold tight for a little while longer – we'll have an event for you soon"*.

I realise this is a relatively new feature on Stack Overflow, but I'm wondering if anyone else has found the currently running events.  It seems a little odd that we should have to wait for an ad to pop up to learn about events in one's area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the product manager in charge of Stack Overflow Careers Select.

There currently is no place on Stack Overflow or Careers where you can see a full list of Select events. It's a new product, and we've been running it in a fashion similar to a closed beta (though as you can tell, we haven't been trying to keep it *super* secret).

Basically, we've been testing out these Select events in a handful of places for a few different types of developer jobs. Since we don't have events for every type of job in every city, we haven't started advertising Select broadly; we don't want to disappoint the majority of our users who won't find one that is relevant to them. (I apologize if you saw an ad for the Toronto event but aren't actually in Toronto; those ads should have only appeared for people we were reasonably confident are in Toronto, but there are a bunch of cases where that targeting is a bit unreliable.)

Additionally, these events are intentionally small and heavily curated. While the product is still new, we've put some restrictions on who can participate. For example, each event has been open only to programmers already living in and around the event city; until we iron out some of the kinks with the product itself, we didn't want to introduce complexity that comes with people interested in relocating to the event city.

Once this experimental phase is complete and we have more concrete plans for serving a broader section of the Stack Overflow community, we'll have plenty of publicly listed information about how you can get involved.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation.  It definitely makes more sense now.